# Anaconda: Can You Simply Copy an Installation / Environment Folder?

Tags: python, anaconda

Reinstalling environments is a huge hassle, I find that exporting and importing doesn't work and you have to manually figure out how to get newer packages to install and work together, so you must keep a log of installation history.

Can I just save the 'Anaconda2' or 'Anaconda3' folder and paste it into a new windows installation? What about 'Anaconda2\envs' or 'Anaconda3\envs'?

Comment: In the Anaconda Navigator there is an option to copy or duplicate (I forget the exact term and not at PC) when you select a non-base environment in the Environment tab

Comment: Might be worth checking out [conda-pack](https://github.com/conda/conda-pack). Never used it, but it's supposedly for packaging relocatable envs.

Answer (score 1):

## Create a conda environment

conda create --name  python=

## To create a requirements.txt file:

```
conda list #Gives you list of packages used for the environment

conda list -e > requirements.txt #Save all the info about packages to your folder
```

## To export environment file

activate 
    conda env export > .yml

## For other person to use the environment

```
conda env create -f <environment-name>.yml
```

Comment: Exporting doesn't work in my experience. You get errors while importing / creating due to package changes and updates.

Comment: In that case you need to specify the exact error because this is the official method of exporting a conda environment as per the documentation.

Comment: Excellent Idea, but it does not work while your target environment has absolutely no internet access where you have to pack the environment yourself

Answer (score 1):

I was just googling around this same questions.  It appears the answer is no, but I haven't actually tried it.  That would be the best way to know for sure.

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/